# Is there a way to use a variable inside an arrow function but initialize it inside another function where the arrow function is also called?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access the variable c that is initialized inside myFunc when I call sum.

```
let sum = (a,b) => {
    let result = a + b + c;
    return result;
}

function myFunc(){
    let c = 5;
    return sum(1,2);
}

console.log(myFunc());
```

But I'm getting an error because of the c that I use inside the arrow function. Don't know if I'm explaining right but I think you get the point by seeing the code above.

Comment: This would work if JavaScript had *dynamic scope* but like many other languages it as *lexical scope*. However, you can simply do `return sum(1,2) + c;` in this case or even `return sum(sum(1,2), c);`.

Comment: It seems like currying would do the trick.

Comment: There are *many* ways to change this code to make it work. Only one thing is clear: no, this as is won't work.

Comment: or add c as a global variable